# Expansion of $x^4\over1+x^2$ into a power series

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series, generating-functions

I calculated the generating function $A(x)$ of the recurrence $a_n = a_{n-2} - 2a_{n-3}$, $(n \ge 0, a_0 = a_1 = 0, a_2 = 2)$ and I have no clue on how to expand it into a power series in order to read the coefficients.

$$A(x) = {-2x^4 \over 1+x^2}.$$

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{1-(-x^2)} = 1 + (-x^2) + (-x^2)^2 + (-x^2)^3 + \dots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generating function is incorrect.

You have the recurrence $$a_n=a_{n-2}-2a_{n-3}+2[n=2]\;,$$ where the last term is an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), and I assume that $a_n=0$ for $n<0$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_{n-2}x^n-2\sum_{n\ge 0}a_{n-3}x^n+2x^2\\
&=x^2A(x)-2x^3A(x)+2x^2\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $$A(x)=\frac{2x^2}{1-x^2+2x^3}\;.$$

Your function is

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{-2x^4}{1+x^2}&=-2x^4\cdot\frac1{1-(-x^2)}\\
&=-2x^4\sum_{n\ge 0}(-x^2)^n\\
&=-2x^4\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nx^{2n}\;,
\end{align*}$$

in which the coefficient of $x^2$ and of every odd power of $x$ is $0$. However, $a_2=2\ne 0$, and $a_3=a_1-2a_0=0$, so $a_5=a_3-2a_2=-4\ne 0$.

Comment: @BrianMScott I got it but I don't see why you added the term $2[n=2]$.

Comment: @saadtaame: To get the correct value for $a_2$. Without that term, the recurrence generates $a_n=0$ for all $n$. Remember, I’m assuming that $a_n=0$ for negative $n$. Thus, without the extra term I have $a_2=a_0-2a_{-1}=0$; with it I have $a_2=a_0-2a_{-1}+2=2$.

Comment: @BrianMScott Damn nice trick.

Comment: @saadtaame: I learned it from *Concrete Mathematics*, by Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, one of my favorite texts ever, both as user and as teacher.

Comment: @BrianMScott Do we always have to start the summation at $n=0$? I started at $n=3$, that was my error maybe.

Comment: @saadtaame: I find it easiest always to start at $n=0$ and add one or more Iverson terms if necessary. That way I automatically get the generating function when I sum both sides of the recurrence over $n\ge 0$.

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks: I lost the coefficient of $2$ on the $x^3$ term in the denominator. Try it with $\frac{2x^2}{1-x^2+2x^3}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: That is the answer I got.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How to find a closed form for the recurrence if there is one?

Comment: @saadtaame: Suppose that $r,s$, and $t$ are the zeroes of $2x^3-x^2+1$; then $(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)=x^3-\frac12x^2+\frac12$, and $A(x)=\frac{x^2}{(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)}$, and you can decompose it into partial fractions. The problem is finding $r,s$, and $t$; they can be found exactly, but [the algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) is messy. [This page](http://www.1728.org/cubic.htm) gives the approximate values $-0.6572981061383739$ and $ 0.5786490530691869\pm0.6525757632523738i$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: geometric series.  $1/(1+x^2) = 1/(1-r)$ where $r = ?$

But this is the wrong generating function.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, your generating function is wrong. Suppose that
$$
A(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\tag{1}
$$
Then by the initial conditions and the recurrence we get that
$$
\begin{align}
A(x)
&=2x^2+\sum_{k=3}^\infty(a_{k-2}-2a_{k-3})x^k\\
&=2x^2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^{k+2}-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{k+3}\\
&=2x^2+\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{k+2}-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{k+3}\\[4pt]
&=2x^2+(x^2-2x^3)A(x)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
And solving $(2)$ for $A(x)$ yields the generating function to be
$$
A(x)=\frac{2x^2}{1-x^2+2x^3}\tag{3}
$$

Comment: With the correction to [Brian M. Scott's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/185202), this is now just a verification.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure I understood I'm doing this example. I hope I got it right this one.

$$
a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2}\\a_0=1, a_1=3
$$

$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}+1[n=0]+1[n=1]$$

$$
A(x)=\sum_{n>=0} a_nx^n=2\sum_{n>=0}a_{n-1}x^n+4\sum_{n>=0}a_{n-2}x^n+1+x
$$

$$
=2xA(x)+4x^2A(x)+1+x
$$

We get:
$$
A(x)={1+x\over 1-2x-4x^2}
$$